# How to use DataGrid with React and render the react component in PowerBI visual.ts file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to create a component.tsx with the following code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridRowsProp } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

export interface NewTestProps {
  rows: GridRowsProp;
  columns: GridColDef[];
}

class NewTest extends React.Component<NewTestProps> {

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    const { rows, columns } = this.props;  
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  // Define user-defined rows and columns
  const userDefinedRows: GridRowsProp = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alice', age: 25 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Bob', age: 30 },
  ];

  const userDefinedColumns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
    { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 150 },
    { field: 'age', headerName: 'Age', width: 90 }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NewTest rows={userDefinedRows} columns={userDefinedColumns} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Now I want to render this code in visual.ts of PowerBI application:

```
export class Visual implements IVisual {
    private target: HTMLElement;
    private updateCount: number;
    private textNode: Text;
    private formattingSettings: VisualFormattingSettingsModel;
    private formattingSettingsService: FormattingSettingsService;
    //private target: HTMLElement;
    //private host: IVisualHost;
    private categories: HTMLElement;
    private table: HTMLParagraphElement;
    reactRoot: React.CElement<any, React.Component<any, any, any>>;
    
    
        constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
            console.log("Testing1////////////");
            // constructor body
            this.target = options.element;
            //this.host = options.host;
            this.table = document.createElement("div");
            this.target.appendChild(this.table);
            // ...
            this.target.appendChild(this.table);

        
         // Define user-defined rows and columns for NewTest component
         const userDefinedRows: GridRowsProp = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Test1', age: 25 },
            { id: 2, name: 'Test2', age: 30 },
            
        ];
        const userDefinedColumns: GridColDef[] = [
            { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
            { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 150 },
            { field: 'age', headerName: 'Age', width: 90 },
            
        ];
        
        
        // Create NewTestProps with user-defined rows and columns
        const newTestProps: NewTestProps = {
            rows: userDefinedRows,
            columns: userDefinedColumns,
        };
        console.log("Testing1////////////");
        console.log(typeof React.createElement(NewTest, newTestProps as React.Attributes));
        

        // const cp = React.createElement(NewTest, newTestProps as React.Attributes); // Create NewTest component
        this.reactRoot = React.createElement(NewTest, newTestProps as React.Attributes); // Create NewTest component
        ReactDOM.render(this.reactRoot, this.table); // Render NewTest component

        /**
         * 1. html node
         * 2. react.render(node, component)
         */
            
        }
    
        public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
            const dataView: DataView = options.dataViews[0];
            const tableDataView: DataViewTable = dataView.table;
            
        if (!tableDataView) {
            return
        }
        while(this.table.firstChild) {
            this.table.removeChild(this.table.firstChild);
        }
    
            //draw header
        const tableHeader = document.createElement("th");
        tableDataView.columns.forEach((column: DataViewMetadataColumn) => {
            const tableHeaderColumn = document.createElement("td");
            tableHeaderColumn.innerText = column.displayName
            tableHeader.appendChild(tableHeaderColumn);
        });
        this.table.appendChild(tableHeader);

        //draw rows
        tableDataView.rows.forEach((row: DataViewTableRow) => {
            const tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
            row.forEach((columnValue: PrimitiveValue) => {
                const cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.innerText = columnValue.toString();
                tableRow.appendChild(cell);
            })
            this.table.appendChild(tableRow);
        }); 
    }
```

But I receive an error on line

> this.reactRoot = React.createElement(NewTest, newTestProps as
> React.Attributes); // Create NewTest component

as :

> ERROR in /Users/Documents/swf/newtest/src/visual.ts ./src/visual.ts
> 155:8-22 [tsl] ERROR in
> /Users/Documents/swf/newtest/src/visual.ts(155,9)
> TS2322: Type 'FunctionComponentElement<{}>' is not assignable to type 'CElement<any, Component<any, any, any>>'.   Types of property
> 'type' are incompatible.
> Type 'FunctionComponent<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<any, any>'.
> Type 'FunctionComponent<{}>' provides no match for the signature 'new (props: any, context?: any): Component<any, any, any>'.
> ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14  @
> ./.tmp/precompile/visualPlugin.ts 1:0-42 10:12-18 11:23-29